# how to use dsm dependency matrix for a grails project in IntelliJ?

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea, dependencies

When running

> Analyze | Analyze Dependecy Matrix

in IntelliJ 13.1 Ultimate on a grails 2.3.7 project a error messages pops up:

```
No class files were found.
DSM analysis can't be performed.
```

However the class files are in `target/classes` and `target/test-classes`. The project setup uses `target/classes` for "project compiler output", the modules inherit project setup for output path.

1. Is DSM analysis supposed to work only on java code or are other JVM languages (namely groovy) supported as well?
2. Any hints what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Works in 12.1.*. Haven't used it yet in 13.1.

Comment: tried 12.1 as well - same result as in 13.1 for me.

Comment: Did you try to build the project? I think DSM works and class files and you need to build the project first